# can a row in mysql reference itself?

Tags: mysql, subquery

Can a row in mysql reference itself in a sub-query?

```
test_table
id |  field 1  | field 2 | field 3
 1 |    25     |   10    | average of field 1 and 2
```

is it possible to have column 3 reference itself?

Thanks.

Comment: If the field3 can be calculated, it shouldn't be in your database. You can calculated field3 in your select statement, is that what you want need know how?

Comment: Why would you want to do this is my first question?   If you are wanting to average it, why not average it before inserting it, or return an additional column in your Select statement that is an average of the two?

Comment: I want this to happen automatically like the can the structure of the column 3 be a select statement which will calculate that upon input in fields 1 and 2?

Comment: I am wanting to do like you are suggesting in part 2 of your comment but don't want to have to create it each time? additionally it would make easier for using that number in other tables and functions, views etc down the line

Answer (score 1):

You can set row 3 equal to the average of columns 1 and 2 at any point, but that value will only be true for the values of those columns at that point in time.

If you're looking for an Excel-style field that automatically updates the column when you change a different column, then you'll want to use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) that will update the third column when either the first or second is updated.

Comment: If a field can be calculated, it should never be stored in the database. Basic DB rule.

Comment: I agree, but that has already been made clear to the asker. I think it's still useful to explain to someone how to do something even if it doesn't conform to best-practices.

Comment: @FrancisP you may be interested to hear that StackOverflow's schema stores columns that *can* be calculated from other columns.  It's known as selective denormalization, and is an accepted practice for performance tuning.

Comment: Thanks for the link on the triggers,  and i am trying to make something that would behave like the way excel would i.e. put in a value in field 1 and work with that value and put in a new column or cell without user interaction on that column.

Comment: @FrancisP: I totally agree with BobbyW and MattFenwick. Sometimes the cost of calculating those values is too much so it is a good idea to consider storing them in a new field. +1, btw.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you want the value to be returned in your select statement, use this:

```
SELECT id, field1, field2,  (CAST((field1 + field2) as DECIMAL)/2) AS 'field 3' 
FROM tablename
```

Casting the sum into decimal will prevent losing precision in your average.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this when creating a table or altering a table.

Comment: I don't think so. The most common way would be to use triggers, like Bobby W mentionned.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple calculation like that, wouldn't you rather have it referenced in a php function instead? Storing it in the database is an unnecessary use of space.

Comment: Im not concearned  for space on the db